# Aws LightSail - Start instance based at an event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-lightsail

I want to automatically start an instance that turned off.

I already have a lambda function to turn off and on, working properly. CloudWatch seems to be the way to do this in an automatic way, but im getting nowhere about to launch the lambda function when the machine turns off.

How to do it?

Searched aws knowledgebase, but no sucess with Lighsail.

Comment: Question: Your lambda knows exactly which instance to start ? How do you get the instance id? You need aws eventbridge for it. You case is event based, so create a rule based on event and give target as your lambda function. If you do not know the instance id, you will need a step function in which another lambda gets the id's for you.

Comment: Also, don't forget to pass input to you step function if you need it. In my case my step function needs tags, which I pass in json.